# Drawing a line between two words in the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drawing

I have a page full of text with repetitive words, and I need to find a way to map the similar words together by drawing a line between them. (it doesn't matter if it crosses the word or if it goes around it).
What is the best way/library to do that using javascript/jquery?

The text is fixed, and the line drawing is the dynamic part. (depending on the word you choose).

Comment: html isn't something you can "draw" on. you could use a canvas element, or float a transparent PICTURE of a line and stretch it appropriately

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904445/draw-continuous-lines-on-html-canvas-one-after-the-other/ , though may be able to use `hr` element with `position:absolute` set ? Can include `html` , `css`, `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: What have you tried? Does the line need to update if the browser is resized? I answered something similar very recently for [drawing lines between data in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33988943/145346).

Comment: Maybe try this [jQuery highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin instead of drawing lines?

Comment: @Mottie, thanks for the responses. Actually I need to highlight the words too but I knew how to do that so I didn't ask about it. The table idea is interesting though.

Comment: @Mark B, it will come down to using canvases (probably) but even with that it's not easy.

Comment: It would help if you provided some HTML and some attempt at code or this question will get closed.